# Change an image on a html web page using javascript depending on an ID

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am fairly new to JavaScript and i am trying to display an image which changes depending on an ID which the user types in.

Below i have declared a variable "icon" to store the values of the url + the icon id + .png to complete the url :

```
icon = "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.2.1/img/profileicon/" + summonerIcon + ".png"
```

An example of what this variable could contain is: `"http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.2.1/img/profileicon/14.png"`

I would like to use the information in this variable to display on my html page, so when a user types in a username, the javascript should return an image which matches the ID which the user has submitted.

These images are all stored at the url displayed above, they are not stored locally.

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: What have you got with you, the HTML? Can you post it too?

Comment: This should give you hint.. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_src.asp ...

Comment: so the image is not in the same domain as the page? this is not a good idea, maybe you should download and store locally those images. if the CC allows you to do so and use those assets.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to hook into a change event on the input which would dictate the ID and then pull the value into the icon variable.

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="userid" id="id />
```

JS

```
function getVals() {
  var icon = $( "#id" ).val();
}

$( "input" ).change( getVals );
getVals();
```

You'll have to tweak the getVals function to it re-renders the image you are displaying, but this should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This uses [jquery](http://jquery.com/download/) plugin.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#btnLoad').click(function(e){
            var baseUrl ='http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.2.1/img/profileicon/';
            $('#iconHolder').attr('src', baseUrl + $('#iconId').val() + '.png');
        });
    });
</script>
Icon Id <input id="iconId" /><button id="btnLoad">Load</button>
<br/>
<img id="iconHolder" />
```